# Is there a word that means “measure time”?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, time

You can measure the weight – it is called weighing.

If you measure time, what is that called? Is there a single English word for this?

I'm thinking especially in the context of measuring the performance of something, for example, to measure the time it takes for a computer program to complete a specific task or to measure the time it takes a runner to run 100 meters.

Comment: For a program specifically on (any variant of) Unix, the standard command "time" shows "real" (elapsed) and "CPU" time of an execution. (These are actually _measured_ by the operating system for all processes, but normally discarded; "time" preserves and shows them.)

Comment: The term analogous to "weight" would be "duration".  The *duration* of the speech was 37 minutes.  As to what the activity is, I would call it "chronologicalizing".

Comment: @HotLicks Not [chronometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronometry)?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you're measuring the time it takes a runner to run 100 meters, you are *timing* the runner, or *clocking* the runner.

From *Merriam-Webster* dictionary:

> [Clock:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clock) *transitive verb* 1a:  to time with a stopwatch or by an electric timing device
>
> [Time:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/time)
> *transitive verb* 4. to determine or record the time, duration, or rate of

Comment: +1 When measuring a bullet you might also use the verb form of [chronograph.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chronograph#Verb)

Comment: Not a verb, but related: "A **[timekeeper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timekeeper)** [...] is an instrument or person that measures the passage of time."

Comment: This is the right answer. When determining why a program is running more slowly than expected, the program is ***profiled*** to identify bottlenecks.

Comment: Thanks Peter; I considered using _clock_ but was hesitant as I wasn't sure whether the word could be used in that way in English (it can in Swedish).

Comment: @jxh _Profiling_ is a good description of what you are doing when you are measuring the time it takes for a program to run, but it is less specific as it may also mean that you are measuring allocated memory.

Comment: I would use *profiling* to mean figuring out which specific parts of a computer program are taking up the most computation time, and not simply measuring how much time it takes to run.

Comment: Be aware that to **clock someone** also means to notice them, or hit them (_slang_), see [StackExchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79775/origin-of-using-clocked-to-mean-noticed).

Comment: I agree with both Peter and Hello. I didn't offer *profile* as an answer, since it is actually measuring many things about how the program is running, not just how long it takes to perform a specific task. In the specific case of timing a specific task, the profile would reveal how long each of its "subtasks" were taking.

Comment: To 'clock' can mean to measure *speed*.

Comment: @Lumberjack Chronographing is basically [never used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chronographing%2Cclocking&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchronographing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cclocking%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Meant to [include timing](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chronographing%2Cclocking%2Ctiming&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchronographing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cclocking%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctiming%3B%2Cc0), which makes it even more of a rounding error.

Answer (score 29):

***[To time](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/time)*** conveys the meaning you want:

> If you time an action or activity, you measure how long someone takes to do it or how long it lasts.
>
> - He timed each performance with a stop-watch.

(Collins Dictionary)

Answer (score 6):

Specifically the English words **Chronometry** or **Horology** mean the science or technique of the accurate measurement of time. This is "**time keeping**". Horology also means the art of making timepieces.

[Chronometry TFD link](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/chronometry)

[Horology TFD link](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/horology)

[Chronometry Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronometry)

Comment: He seems to be looking for a verb, since the analogy he gave was "weighing".

Comment: I know. I wanted to add these anyway.